# Handling and logging exception raise by exception handler class in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, aop

I have an exception handler method in the exception handler class of my spring boot project.

I came to know that, the `throws` keyword can not handle the exception in the exception handler class.

So, I'm using the `try-catch` block to handle it. (Please suggest if there is any better way).

And I want to log the exception handled by `catch` block, using AOP.

How should I trigger the method in AOP to log this exception handled by `catch` block?

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

*Error DTO class with Clonable implemented*

```
@Component
public class ErrorDTO implements Cloneable{
    
    private String message;
    private Integer errorCode;
    private LocalDateTime timeStamp;
    
    // Getters & Setters...
    
    @Override
    public ErrorDTO clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (ErrorDTO) super.clone();
    }
    
    
}
```

*Exception Controller class*

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {

    @Autowired
    ErrorDTO errorDTO;
    
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<List<ErrorDTO>> handlerMethod(MethodArgumentNotValidException e){
        
        List<ErrorDTO> errorDTOs = new ArrayList<>();
        
        e.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach(
                
                error -> {
                    errorDTO.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE.value());
                    errorDTO.setMessage(error.getDefaultMessage());
                    errorDTO.setTimeStamp(LocalDateTime.now());
                    
                    try {
                        errorDTOs.add(errorDTO.clone());
                    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                
                );
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDTOs, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    
    }
    
}
```

Here,
Inside the `handlerMethod(MethodArgumentNotValidException e)` method `errorDTOs.add(errorDTO.clone());` need to be surrounded by `try-catch` block to handle `CloneNotSupportedException` exception.

How can I trigger a method in Logging Aspect to Log this exception handled by `catch` block here?

And also, is there any other way to handle such exceptions?

(I'm open to any other relevant suggestions, to follow the best practices)

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: This could be a use case for the native AspectJ `handler()` pointcut. But in order to be sure, you need to provide a clear, complete, minimal reproducer ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Then I can help you.

Comment: Hi, @kriegaex Thank you for your comment, following your suggestion,  I've added a Minimal Reproducible Example in the question, please have a look.

Comment: Am I assuming correctly that you want to have an exception handler B for your exception handler A? Isn't that a bit over-engineered? Why don't you log the error in the exception handler and maybe put some info about the problem into your error DTO? I am not a Spring user, so I cannot tell you if a second `@RestControllerAdvice` can intercept errors from the first one, but probably not. Like I said, a native AspectJ aspect would work, but think about whether it is worth to switch from Spring AOP to AspectJ just to avoid a try-catch block.

Comment: @kriegaex I got your point, in fact, the actual question is, is there any way to trigger a logging method using AOP in this situation, Instead of getting a logger object just for one log.

Comment: What stops you from using a static logger and/or share a logger for exception logging from a utility class? Anyway, like I said, if you want to use an aspect, you can.